# Using asp.net MVC membership for authentication in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

We have an asp.net MVC site that uses the membership provider for authentication. We'd like to use that provider in a xamarin app we are developing (iOS & Android). I've been scouring google for a few hours and I'm not having any luck finding examples on this topic (Most use Google or FaceBook OAuth providers.) Can anyone assist on:

- Is this even possible?
- Anyone aware of a good walkthrough on this topic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create your own website OAuth log on like Google and FaceBook?

Comment: I mean we want to utilize the usernames and passwords already in the MVC site for authentication on the mobile app.

Comment: Do you have a URL for your site that can take a username and password using basic authentication? 
Perhaps this guide may help: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/rest/

Comment: Thanks, I think I finally found a decent walkthrough. I'll post the link once I verify it works.

Comment: @AS2012 did the walkthrough you found work? Mind posting a link?

Comment: which walk through you found? can you post your link please?